# Why can't I run node.js & socket.io in a screen or with Forever?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, express, socket.io

I've got some annoying problem and that is I have trouble in running nodejs in a screen. Because as fast as I leave the screen and no sockets are connected the next whom is to connect will be faced by an error message until the screen is opened again. As soon as the screen is open with `screen -R node` (for example) it will start accepting connections again.

However notice that if the screen is closed (running in the background) and someone already has a socket open, it will continue to answer new connections.

When I try to start the application again, with the command `node app` I get the following message:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '(unreachable)/square_defense/app'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

**Server side code**:

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(__dirname);
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('user-message', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        sendMessage.call(socket, data.message);
    });
});
var sendMessage = function(message) {
      this.emit('server-message', {message: message});
      this.broadcast.emit('server-message', {message: message});
}
```

I have tried a lot of things like `npm install app` in directory `..` from the app.js. Can't understand why it dont want to work. I really just want a server which I can use for testing purposes that do not crash.

**EDIT:** I think this has something to do with an encrypted home folder?

I think the unreachable folder is where the problem resides. Error: Cannot find module '**(unreachable)**/square_defense/app'. But I don't know why this is happening. Right now I am running the application with Forever and as soon as I have an ssh-session on it will work. But as soon as I exit the connection and reload the page. It will generate an error.

Comment: @Riwels Yes, ubuntu 12.04 to be exact.

Comment: Hmm... I probably have this issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72229/unreachable-home-folder

Comment: It was to recommend you to use forever. You know it now. =)

Comment: I'll have to take this back, forever seems to cause the same problem but with an interesting fling. If I am connected via ssh to my server it works fine, no problems. But as soon as I close my ssh-session and reload the page I get this: `Error: ENOENT, stat '/home/jarvis/square_defense/index.html'` the same as before and I can only guess that that it has the same error as above internally.

I think I'll have to bounty this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, your home directory is encrypted, and according to [the document from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome):

> This directory is automatically mounted on login, and unmounted on logout.

So your guess is correct, this is exact what's causing the error. Running a detached `screen` session won't be considered by the OS as the user are still logged in*. The time all shell sessions of the user ends, the encrypted home directory got unmounted.

---

Solution: You can move your app to a directory other than `$HOME`, then I think either *GNU Screen* or *forever* will do the job without errors.†

---

<sub>* You can test this by your self: login, start a `screen` session, run something like `vim`, detach; use command `w` to see who is logged in and what they are doing</sub>

<sub>† I think if you write your own upstart scripts for this, it is still crucial that the app files are not placed in auto-encrypted home directory.</sub>

Comment: Dude, thanks for this. I am going to try this and will be back after I've tested it a bit. Then tomorrow if everything looks fine. You'll have your reward :)

Comment: Seems to still be working after I moved the files outside my home directory. Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already are on an Ubuntu box, i recommend using [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) and [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) as described in this post: http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit

The only thing i added into the mix was a frontend proxy-server (HAProxy in my case, but nginx works as well) in order to serve my application on port 80.

I deployed a socket.io/express app using this technology stack on Amazon EC2 myself about a month ago, with amazing results!

**EDIT:**

Here are some resources i collected over time concerning a proper production setup using node.js/nginx/monit/git:

- http://cuppster.com/2011/05/12/diy-node-js-server-on-amazon-ec2/ (an awesome guide, helped me a lot!)
- http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit

I really recommend the first one, you might have to skip some parts (like npm module installation or system setup), but the parts about nginx/git and supervisor are worth a read.

Comment: well I'm pretty sure I would get the same error with upstart and monit. I don't see the need of a proxy server :) I don't need a load balancer!

Comment: the use of upstart and monit is not specifically to solve your problem, it's rather a really good way to keep node services up and running. Since i never used screen (always seemed sketchy to me) i can't give you a proper opinion on that one. And btw: HAProxy is not a load balancer in this scenario, its just a frontend-server for your application-servers ;) EDIT: oh, and i'm pretty sure that this setup would solve your issue...

Comment: Well right now I use forever that will restart the application if it goes down (it says). But when I use `forever list` I get
`info:    No forever processes running` even if there are processes clearly running.

Comment: the funny thing is that I can restart it, and it will work for a while. I am unsure for how long. But eventually it will crash. Can this occur because the sockets timeout and I don't handle them?

Comment: i only used forever on my local development machine with an open terminal session, i really can't give you advice on this one. As soon as i've been working on remote servers, i always pulled up an upstart/monit/nginx setup with git-hooks to restart the service on deployment...sorry :/

Comment: Can you link me to a guide to setup nginx with git-hooks? I have experience with setting up nginx but not with git-hooks and it sounds interesting. If you can help me with this and no one else gives me an answer to my real problem. I will give you the 200 reputation :)